# Easy to read one-liner to test string contains substrings in any order with wildcarded patterns

Tags: groovy

I was not able to find any examples of wildcards with containsAll so not sure if it supports it.

I want to check if a series of substrings are contained in a string in any order AND wildcard some of those strings.

The simplest way to do this seems to be like this *if* containsAll supports wildcards somehow:

```
myString = "aaa somePrefix-blahblah ddd"
// "somePrefix-*" doesnt work but shows what I would like to achieve
assert myString.split().toList().containsAll("aaa", "somePrefix-*", "ddd")
```

I'm looking for a simple, easy to read one-liner to express this- avoiding a more complicated multiline routine.

Comment: You could use a regular expression pattern, and do: `assert ["aaa", ~/somePrefix-.*/, "ddd"].every { p -> myString.split().any { it ==~ p } }`

Comment: hmm if thats the best one-liner way then I think a regular for loop is the way to go for me because thats not super readable

Comment: actually using regex like that works for me so I would mark that as an answer. I guess its just user preference but I will go with this instead because I think its a little easier to read `​myString.split().each{assert it ==~ "aaa | somePrefix-.*| ddd"}`. I _think_ that regex does essentially the same thing

Comment: That's correct (so long as you lose the spaces) `"aaa|somePrefix-.*| ddd"` however, I had a thought...  is `"aaa tim somePrefix-blahblah ddd"` a valid string (with the extra `tim`) it's not clear from your question whether every word in the string has to match, or whether every string just has to contain the 3 things you're looking for (and can contain other stuff in addition)